# Screen's off when using camera (Android)

Tags: android

is there any way to keep the screen awake (don't want that it turns off) when I'm previewing the camera?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [WakeLock](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/02/07/android-wakelock/)

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
        pm.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My wakelook");
// This will make the screen and power stay on
// This will release the wakelook after 1000 ms
wakeLock.acquire(1000);

// Alternative you can request and / or  release the wakelook via:
// wakeLock.acquire(); wakeLock.release();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Use this it works for me !